# Don't know how to transform variable entity into relational table

Tags: database-design, subtypes

### INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:

The following example illustrates the problem I face:

*Animal* has a race, which can be a *cat* or a *dog*. *Cat* can be either *Siamese* or *Persian*. *Dog* can be a *German shepherd* or *Labrador retriver*.

*Animal is a strong entity, while its race is an attribute that can have one of the two offered values ( cat or a dog ).* *Both these values are complex ( I have added here only the type of dog/cat to illustrate the problem, but there can also be the cat's / dog's name and bunch of other stuff ).*

### PROBLEM:

I don't know how to create relational tables for this example.

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM:

I have tried to draw ER diagram, using Chen's notation, that represents the problem but being a beginner I don't know if I did it right. Here is what I have got:

[image]

I apologize if I drew something wrong, please correct me if that is the case. I don't wish to simply get "free solution" but also to learn how to deal with this problem so I can solve it on my own in the future.

The only thing that comes to my mind is to create two separate tables, one for cats and one for dogs. Also, the *race* attribute in the *Animal* table would only store *cat* or a *dog* value. Something like this:

```
Animal< # Animal_ID, race, other attributes >
Cat < # Cat_ID, $ Animal_ID, breed >
Dog < # Dog_ID, $ Animal_ID, breed >
```

I really have a bad feeling about my solution and I fear it is wrong, hence the below question.

### QUESTIONS:

- How can I transform my example into ER diagram ?
- How to transform that ER diagram into relational tables?

*If further info is required leave a comment and I will update my post as soon as possible. Also feel free to add appropriate tags since I am fairly new here.*

Thank you.

Comment: The transformation of EER diagrams to tables can be found in this paper from 1986 of [T.J.Teorey, D.Yang,J.P.Fry: A Logical Design Methodology for Relational Databases Using the Extended Entity-Relationship Model](http://paginas.fe.up.pt/~jmoreira/wwwsi/2000-01/eerm.pdf). It is straightforward and one of my favorite papers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The proper structure for this scenario is a SubClass / Inheritance model, and is nearly identical to the concept I proposed in this answer: [Heterogeneous ordered list of value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71741/heterogeneous-ordered-list-of-value/72319#72319).

The model proposed in this question is actually quite close in that the `Animal` entity contains the type (i.e. `race`) and the properties that are common across all types. However, there are two minor changes that are needed:

1. Remove the Cat_ID and Dog_ID fields from their respective entities:

   The key concept here is that *everything* is an `Animal`, regardless of `race`: `Cat`, `Dog`, `Elephant`, and so on. Given that starting point, any particular `race` of `Animal` doesn't truly need a separate identifier since:

   1. the `Animal_ID` is unique
   2. the `Cat`, `Dog`, and any additional `race` entities added in the future do not, by themselves, fully represent any particular `Animal`; they only have meaning when used in combination with the information contained in the parent entity, `Animal`.

   Hence, the `Animal_ID` property in the `Cat`, `Dog`, etc entities is both the PK and the FK back to the `Animal` entity.
2. Differentiate between types of `breed`:

   Just because two properties share the same name does not *necessarily mean* that those properties are the same, even if the name being the same *implies* such a relationship. In this case, what you really have is actually `CatBreed` and `DogBreed` as seperate "types"

### Initial Notes

1. The SQL is specific to Microsoft SQL Server (i.e. is T-SQL). Meaning, be careful about datatypes as they are not the same across all RDBMS's. For example, I am using `VARCHAR` but if you need to store anything outside of the standard ASCII set, you should really use `NVARCHAR`.
2. The ID fields of the "type" tables (`Race`, `CatBreed`, and `DogBreed`) are *not* auto-incrementing (i.e. IDENTITY in terms of T-SQL) because they are application constants (i.e. they are part of the application) that are static lookup values in the database and are represented as `enum`s in C# (or other languages). If values are added, they are added in controlled situations. I reserve the use of auto-increment fields for user data that comes in via the application.
3. The naming convention I use is to name each subclass table starting with the main class name followed by the subclass name. This helps organize the tables as well as indicates clearly (without looking at the FKs) the relationship of the subclass table to the main entity table.
4. Please see "Final Edit" section at the end for a note regarding Views.

### "Breed" as "Race"-Specific Approach

[image: Breed As Race-specific Diagram]
This first set of tables are the lookup / types tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Race
(
  RaceID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  RaceName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CatBreed
(
  CatBreedID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  BreedName VARCHAR(50),
  CatBreedAttribute1 INT,
  CatBreedAttribute2 VARCHAR(10)
  -- other "CatBreed"-specific properties as needed
);

CREATE TABLE DogBreed
(
  DogBreedID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  BreedName VARCHAR(50),
  DogBreedAttribute1 TINYINT
  -- other "DogBreed"-specific properties as needed
);
```

This second listing is the main "Animal" entity:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Animal
(
  AnimalID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  RaceID INT NOT NULL, -- FK to Race
  Name VARCHAR(50)
  -- other "Animal" properties that are shared across "Race" types
);

ALTER TABLE Animal
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Animal_Race]
  FOREIGN KEY (RaceID)
  REFERENCES Race (RaceID);
```

This third set of tables are the complimentary sub-class entities that complete the definition of each `Race` of `Animal`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE AnimalCat
(
  AnimalID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- FK to Animal
  CatBreedID INT NOT NULL, -- FK to CatBreed
  HairColor VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  -- other "Cat"-specific properties as needed
);

ALTER TABLE AnimalCat
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AnimalCat_CatBreed]
  FOREIGN KEY (CatBreedID)
  REFERENCES CatBreed (CatBreedID);

ALTER TABLE AnimalCat
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AnimalCat_Animal]
  FOREIGN KEY (AnimalID)
  REFERENCES Animal (AnimalID);


CREATE TABLE AnimalDog
(
  AnimalID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- FK to Animal
  DogBreedID INT NOT NULL, -- FK to DogBreed
  HairColor VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  -- other "Dog"-specific properties as needed
);

ALTER TABLE AnimalDog
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AnimalDog_DogBreed]
  FOREIGN KEY (DogBreedID)
  REFERENCES DogBreed (DogBreedID);

ALTER TABLE AnimalDog
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AnimalDog_Animal]
  FOREIGN KEY (AnimalID)
  REFERENCES Animal (AnimalID);
```

*The model using a shared `breed` type is shown after the "Additional Notes" section.*

### Additional Notes

1. The concept of `breed` seems to be a focal point for confusion. It was suggested by jcolebrand (in a comment on the question) that `breed` is a property shared across the different `race`s, and the other two answers have it integrated as such in their models. This is a mistake, however, because the values for `breed` are not shared across the different values of `race`. Yes, I am aware that the two other proposed models attempt to solve this issue by making `race` a parent of `breed`. While that technically solves the relationship issue, it doesn't help solve the overall modeling question of what to do about non-common properties, nor how to handle a `race` that does not have a `breed`. But, in the case that such a property were guaranteed to exist across all `Animal`s, I will include an option for that as well (below).
2. The models proposed by vijayp and DavidN (which seem to be identical) do not work because:

   1. They either

      1. do not allow for non-common properties to be stored (at least not for individual instances of any `Animal`), or
      2. require that all properties for all `race`s be stored in the `Animal` entity which is a very flat (and nearly non-relational) way of representing this data. Yes, people do this all of the time, but it means having many NULL fields per row for the properties that are not meant for that particular `race` AND knowing which fields per row are associated with the particular `race` of that record.
   2. They do not allow for adding a `race` of `Animal` in the future that does not have `breed` as a property. And even if ALL `Animal`s have a `breed`, that wouldn't change the structure due to what has been previously noted about `breed`: that `breed` is dependent on the `race` (i.e. `breed` for `Cat` is not the same thing as `breed` for `Dog`).

### "Breed" as Common- / Shared- Property Approach

[image]
Please note:

1. The SQL below can be run in the same database as the model presented above:

   1. The `Race` table is the same
   2. The `Breed` table is new
   3. The three `Animal` tables have been appended with a `2`
2. Even with `Breed` being a now common property, it does not seem right not to have `Race` noted in the main/parent entity (even if it is technically relationally correct). So, both `RaceID` and `BreedID` are represented in `Animal2`. In order to prevent a mismatch between the `RaceID` noted in `Animal2` and a `BreedID` that is for a different `RaceID`, I have added a FK on both `RaceID, BreedID` that references a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT of those fields in the `Breed` table. I usually despise pointing a FK to a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, but here is one of the few valid reasons to do so. A UNIQUE CONSTRAINT is logically an "Alternate Key", which makes it valid for this use. Please also note that the `Breed` table still has a PK on just `BreedID`.

   1. The reason for not going with just a PK on the combined fields and no UNIQUE CONSTRAINT is that it would allow for the same `BreedID` to be repeated across different values of `RaceID`.
   2. The reason for not switching which the PK and UNIQUE CONSTRAINT around is that this might not be the only usage of `BreedID`, so it should still be possible to reference a specific value of `Breed` without having the `RaceID` available.
3. While the following model does work, it has two potential flaws regarding the concept of a shared `Breed` (and are why I prefer the `Race`-specific `Breed` tables).

   1. There is an implicit assumption that ALL values of `Breed` have the same properties. There is no easy way in this model to have disparate properties between `Dog` "breeds" and `Elephant` "breeds". However, there still is a way to do this, which is noted in the "Final Edit" section.
   2. There is no way to share a `Breed` across more than one race. I am not sure if that is desirable to do (or maybe not in the concept of animals but possibly in other situations that would be using this type of model), but it is not possible here.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Race
(
  RaceID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  RaceName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Breed
(
  BreedID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  RaceID INT NOT NULL, -- FK to Race
  BreedName VARCHAR(50)
);

ALTER TABLE Breed
  ADD CONSTRAINT [UQ_Breed]
  UNIQUE (RaceID, BreedID);

ALTER TABLE Breed
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Breed_Race]
  FOREIGN KEY (RaceID)
  REFERENCES Race (RaceID);

CREATE TABLE Animal2
(
  AnimalID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  RaceID INT NOT NULL, -- FK to Race, FK to Breed
  BreedID INT NOT NULL, -- FK to Breed
  Name VARCHAR(50)
  -- other properties common to all "Animal" types
);

ALTER TABLE Animal2
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Animal2_Race]
  FOREIGN KEY (RaceID)
  REFERENCES Race (RaceID);

-- This FK points to the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on Breed, _not_ to the PK!
ALTER TABLE Animal2
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Animal2_Breed]
  FOREIGN KEY (RaceID, BreedID)
  REFERENCES Breed (RaceID, BreedID);


CREATE TABLE AnimalCat2
(
  AnimalID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- FK to Animal
  HairColor VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE AnimalCat2
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AnimalCat2_Animal2]
  FOREIGN KEY (AnimalID)
  REFERENCES Animal2 (AnimalID);

CREATE TABLE AnimalDog2
(
  AnimalID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  HairColor VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE AnimalDog2
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AnimalDog2_Animal2]
  FOREIGN KEY (AnimalID)
  REFERENCES Animal2 (AnimalID);
```

### Final Edit (hopefully ;-)

1. Regarding the possibility (and then difficulty) of handling disparate properties between types of `Breed`, it *is* possible to employ the same subclass / inheritance concept but with `Breed` as the main entity. In this setup the `Breed` table would have the properties common to all types of `Breed` (just like the `Animal` table) and `RaceID` would represent the type of `Breed` (same as it does in the `Animal` table). Then you would have subclass tables such as `BreedCat`, `BreedDog`, and so on. For smaller projects this *might* be considered "over-engineering", but it is being mentioned as an option for situations that would benefit from it.
2. For both approaches, it sometimes helps to create Views as short-cuts to the full entities. For example, consider:

   ```
   CREATE VIEW Cats AS
      SELECT  an.AnimalID,
              an.RaceID,
              an.Name,
              -- other "Animal" properties that are shared across "Race" types
              cat.CatBreedID,
              cat.HairColor
              -- other "Cat"-specific properties as needed
      FROM    Animal an
      INNER JOIN  AnimalCat cat
              ON  cat.AnimalID = an.AnimalID
      -- maybe add in JOIN(s) and field(s) for "Race" and/or "Breed"
   ```
3. While not part of the logical entities, it is fairly common to have audit fields in the tables to at least get a sense of when the records are being inserted and updated. So in practical terms:

   1. A `CreatedDate` field would be added to the `Animal` table. This field is not needed in any of the subclass tables (e.g. `AnimalCat`) as the rows being inserted for both tables should be done at the same time within a transaction.
   2. A `LastModifiedDate` field would be added to the `Animal` table and all subclass tables. This field gets updated only if that particular table is updated: if an update occurs in `AnimalCat` but not in `Animal` for a particular `AnimalID`, then only the `LastModifiedDate` field in `AnimalCat` would be set.

Comment: Somehow I get the feeling you understood exactly what my problem is. I will give your linked answer a look, and study it carefully. Just a simple definition of tables would be great as well ( if SQL queries are too much for you to write at the moment ). If you do decide to update your post with SQL queries or table definitions, please leave me a comment. Thank you again. Best regards.

Comment: I am trying to apply your answer to my real life case. If I blindly follow your instructions I believe that I might miss the opportunity to further optimize my design. I would like you to take a look at my latest question since you have been able to perfectly understand my questions, and to provide excellent answers. I have composed the question to use generic data model in order to be useful to future readers as well. If you have trouble finding it leave me a comment. Thank you and sorry for disturbing...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Hi. Got this message earlier but didn't have time to get to it right away. I was able to find the new Question by clicking on your name above and it shows all of your Questions :-).

Comment: I was referring to [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140604/implementing-subtype-of-a-subtype-in-type-subtype-design-pattern-with-mutually-e). In a nutshell: I have 3 entities with common attribute `D`, therefore I wanted to apply method from your answer. Two entities have common attribute `E` which is not present in third entity. Should I ignore this fact and apply standard solution, or is there a way to further optimize my design ?

Answer (score 4):

First off, you are doing well to distinguish between ER modeling and relational modeling.  Many newbies don't.

Here are some buzzwords you can use to look up helpful articles on the web.

Your case is a classic case of class/subclass or, if you like, type/subtype.

The phrase that's used in ER modeling is "generalization/specialization".  And many of the articles show this under something called EER (Enhanced Entity-Relationship) modeling.  This wasn't in Peter Chen's original presentation of ER modeling.  It was added later.  For a pretty good summary of gen/spec in pdf form, [click here](http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/4710/f11/Ch08.pdf)

Next, when converting a class/subclass case to relational modeling you design tables. There is more than one approach. The two main approaches are called single table inheritance and class table inheritance.  Each has advantages and drawbacks.  The best presentation of these two designs comes from Martin Fowler.  You can see his outline [here](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)  and [here](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html).

The big advantage of single table inheritance is simplicity.  It's all stored in one table.  The big drawback is a lot of NULLS.  This can waste space and time and result in confusing logic.

Class table inheritance requires joins, but they are simple and fast.  Especially if you use a technique called shared primary key, in which the PK in the subclass tables is a copy of the PK in the superclass table.  You can create views for each subclass that join superclass data with subclass data.

Finally, there is a tag in this area that collects questions like yours together.
Here it is:  [subtypes](/questions/tagged/subtypes)

Comment: +1 What is confusing me is the lack of primary keys in the table diagrams. Especially in the "classTableInheritance" I cannot see that all these table are connected by the same primary key.

Comment: @miracle173 a valid point.  For some reason, Fowler doesn't include the PKs and FKs in the diagram.  There are other articles under class table inheritance that provide this detail. Not all implementations of class table inheritance combine it with shared primary key.  I recommend it.  It's a little more work at insert time, but easier and faster at joined retrieval time.

Answer (score 3):

I see on possible design as

Table `Race`

```
RaceId- PK- Int
RaceName - Varchar(50)
```

Table `Breed`

```
BreedId - PK- Int
RaceId - FK - Int
BreedName - varchar(50)
```

Table `Animal`

```
AnimalId - PK- Int
BreedId - FK - Int
Other Columns....
```

These PKs above would be auto-incrementing column. Other columns in `Animal` table could be named accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Additionally I would add a fields with keys of Race and Type (could be triggers) in the Animal table in order to facilitate later indexes to improve speed.

Answer (score 0):

Your current method is not bad. However, if you are going to be adding more races later (bird, fish, etc.) then creating a separate table for each could be cumbersome. I would recommend something like the following:

```
Animal < # Animal_ID, Breed_ID, other attributes >
Breed < # Breed_ID, Race_ID >
Race < # Race_ID >
```

A breed, to my understanding, should have only one race. So if you store the breed in the Animal table you will be able to determine the race by joining to the Breed table. Obviously, add any other attributes (name, description, etc.) to Breed and Race tables as needed.