# designing a database with type and sub type

Tags: database-design

I am trying to build a publications database, and i want to develop a genre relation that has various (maybe look up tables) sub-genres attached. as an example, in the genre relation there would be a row for 'POETRY' but somehow i want to divide that into sub genres like 'PROSE', 'HAIKU' or 'FREE_VERSE'.

what is the best way to design such a thing? would i have a separate look-up table for each row in the genre relation for the various sub-genres? that doesn't seem very flexible. any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you be collecting different data for each of the subtypes ('PROSE', 'HAIKU' or 'FREE_VERSE')? Or would the data all be the same for all subtypes of "POETRY"?

Comment: mostly, i am just trying to create a searchable database of various published works. the data rows would be much the same, but the sub types would be used as a classification system... maybe thats not the right way to go about it?

Comment: agreeed @TemporaryName. I'm trying to strike a balance between designing a system that is both flexible and complete, but that i can still write queries against (at my skill level)

Comment: @StillLearningToCode Just to be clear, are there different properties for each genre? I can amend my answer to deal with a simpler case of merely needing to designate subtype but where all Publication types are really the same.

Comment: so originally, i wanted to create a way to search a collection of writings by various attributes. @srutzky, i think the data will all be the same, but the various genre/ sub-genre will be used just as classification for searching stored files.

Comment: @StillLearningToCode So these are all print publications? You won't have any that are audio and/or video or something that is particular to only a subset of the Publications? If that is the case, then, as WalterMitty said, you probably don't need the flexibility of what I suggested. In which case I would then ask if there will always be a SubGenre? The self-referencing FK that Walter mentioned allows for "Poetry" by itself, or "Poetry -> Haiku", or "Poetry -> Haiku -> Silly", and so on. But if you will never want "Poetry" or "Fiction" by themselves, there is another method to do that.

Comment: And I agree with @TemporaryName in that queries should not be the main concern at this point. Queries will be the least of your problems if you get the model wrong. If a simpler structure that requires a sub-genre is more appropriate, then I will amend my answer. If a simpler structure that requires a flexible hierarchy of genre is appropriate, then the accepted answer should be moved from mine to Walter's. Regardless, take some time to think about the nature of the data so that you can provide clearer direction: I would rather give up the 15 pts than contribute to yet more over-engineering.

Comment: I went back and looked at the data files i want to store and they are all in fact printed, no audio of image/video files. I also think that one sub-genre is sufficient, and i think that it is possible to have just a genre without any sub sections...

Comment: @StillLearningToCode I updated my answer (new section below the line) in response to the details you added on May 29th. And just FYI, when more than 2 people are involved in a comments area (attached to a question or to an answer), the people who did not post the question/comment do not get notified of any replies unless their id, prefixed with `@`, is specified (and you can only specify one `@id` per comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems nearly identical to the following question, and my answer there should be detailed enough to explain the concept (and is just too much to copy and paste here).

[Don't know how to transform variable entity into relational table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80951/dont-know-how-to-transform-variable-entity-into-relational-table/81130#81130)

For your case specifically I would think it should work itself out to be something along the lines of:

- `Publication` table is the main entity with the common properties, a PK on `PublicationID`, and a `PublicationTypeID` field that FKs to `PublicationType`
- Lookup table for `PublicationType` that has a PK of `PublicationTypeID`. Entries would be the various genres.
- Sub-class tables for the genres, such as Poetry, Fiction, etc. Each sub-class table has a PK named `PublicationID` that also FKs back to the `Publication` table, and fields for properties that are specific to the particular genre.
- Where applicable, sub-class tables have sub-type field, such as `PoetryTypeID` and FKs to the `PoetryType` table.
- Lookup tables for sub-classes, one table per each sub-class type. The PK would be `PoetryTypeID` (e.g. Prose, Haiku, Free Verse, etc).

---

In light of additional details being made available that give context to the scope of the request (specifically the following comment on the question:

> the data files **...** are all in fact printed, no audio of image/video files. **...** one sub-genre is sufficient, and **...** it is possible to have just a genre without any sub sections..

), it seems clear now that the flexibility allowed for by my suggestion above is not needed as sub-types aren't really being stored. Instead, the request now seems to be for simply a means of categorization. For that, **if you want a rigid structure of Genre / Sub-Genre** such that:

- those are the only two levels, and
- you always know which level you are dealing with (in queries), as opposed to a dynamic structure where each Publication can be associated with a Genre / Sub-Genre at any level (1 through N) and you would need to query to get the heirarchy

then you can do something along the lines of:

```sql
Publication
-------------
PublicationID  INT           NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY
SubGenreID     TINYINT       NOT NULL  FOREIGN KEY  REFERENCES(SubGenre.SubGenreID)
Title          VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL
...


SubGenre
-------------
SubGenreID     TINYINT      NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY
GenreID        TINYINT      NOT NULL  FOREIGN KEY  REFERENCES(Genre.GenreID)
Name           VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL


Genre
-------------
GenreID        TINYINT      NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY
Name           VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
```

In this model you know that what is in the `Publication` table is always the `SubGenre`, and it always has a parent `Genre`. You did say that it is possible to not have a `SubGenre` (though is that really the case?), you can use the same `Name` for both `SubGenre` and `Genre` (e.g. News -> News instead of Poetry -> Bad Teenage).

Or, **if you want a dynamic structure of Genre / Sub-Genre** such that:

- There can be just one level or any number of levels, and
- You can only easily tell if you are either at:

  - a top-level Genre (ParentID IS NULL), or
  - one or more levels deep in SubGenre-land (ParentID IS NOT NULL).

  Else you need to query to get the full hierarchy

then you can do something along the lines of:

```sql
Publication
-------------
PublicationID       INT           NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY
PublicationTypeID   SMALLINT      NOT NULL  FOREIGN KEY
                                              REFERENCES(PublicationType.PublicationTypeID)
Title               VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL
...


PublicationType
-------------
PublicationTypeID        SMALLINT     NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY
ParentPublicationTypeID  SMALLINT     NULL      FOREIGN KEY  
                                              REFERENCES(PublicationType.PublicationTypeID)
Name                     VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
```

Please note that the `ParentPublicationTypeID` field is NULLable, which indicates a top-level item when it is `NULL`. This is the model that [Walter Mitty suggested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102629/designing-a-database-with-type-and-sub-type/102661#102661).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you'll find the "Nested Set Model" for suitable for genres. Some advantages to this are:

1. You can sub-genre things as deeply as your heart desires.
2. You only need 1 table for defining Genres (not counting the associative table between Genre and Publication).

Here's an article that explains it: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

In your case, the tables would like something like so:
[image]

Some sample data:
[image]

For this sample data, "Green Eggs and Ham" are assigned the genres of "Children's", "Prose", and "Poetry". Even though the "Poetry" assignment isn't explicit in the PublicationGenre table, it can be inferred by the fact that "Prose" is a child of "Poetry". Similarly, "Joe's Haiku" is assigned the genres of "Haiku" and "Poetry".

What the "Nested Set Model" would look like for this sample data:
[image]

Comment: The value of this technique depends greatly on which RDBMS is being used. If the implementation will be on MS SQL Server then one can use a proper, self-referencing relationship and query that easily using recursive CTEs (Common Table Expressions) OR use the hierarchyid datatype. And I believe PostgreSQL and/or Oracle can also handle recursive CTEs or at least have similar features. With those options available, this Nested Set Model appears to be clunky (at best). However, it still seems that MySQL (and possibly others) does not have those features, in which case this is a good work-around.

Comment: @srutzky Cool information, I never heard of recursive CTEs. Definitely sounds cleaner that way if the RDBMS supports it.

Answer (score 0):

A solution like class-table-inheritance is probably overkill in this case.  It sounds like you need the same data, in the same fields, for sub genres and genres.  This can all be stored in one lookup table, the PublicationType table.

You need one more field in this table, to record the relationship between sub-genres and genres.  I'll call this field ParentPublicationTypeId.  The entry in the Haiku row would contain the PublicationTypeId for Poetry.  This references a different row in the same table, but it's just another case of a foreign key.  The buzzword is "reflexive relationships" if you want to find further reading.